# User level customised activity feed design

Tags: design, architecture, performance, scalability

I am working creating api for activity feed of user. Feed contains different type of entities.

Before that let me give you bit overview about the app. Its a video app where Users can ask questions then we show results of matched solution. If user watches any of video from matched solution. we show that in feed (all users can view this).  User can like or comment on this entity.

Currently i am generating feed data by aggregating different tables in mysql but this is not very scalable. This method is very slow.

Now, I am thinking of generating feed at the time of when user watches the video then save it in another mysql server dedicated to feed data.
I am running to few problems here :

1. It is user customized feed as we show that if user is commented or liked or not (`is_like`,`is_commented`). Should i save feed data at student level???
2. If i save it as student level.That data will going to be very huge. which database is best suited. I have read that cassandra is best suited for this type of data or just Mysql+redis just work???

Comment: Well hello, fellow Neil.  By feed, you mean video and media?  I agree with your sentiment that this isn't scalable, no.

Comment: @Neil By feed means , twitter/facebook like feed. It contains different type of entities. Instead of creating feed data (by aggregation) at realtime, I am thinking of creating feed data whenver event happens related to feed.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to avoid attempting to hold the media yourself.  Save *links* to videos, not the videos themselves.  If you absolutely must save them yourself, create a file with a randomly generated name on your server and in your database, you save the file path to that file.  If all else fails, at the very least don't put the blob holding the media contents *in the same table* but create a separate table with a one-to-one relationship.  That said, don't try to hold the data yourself because as you correctly indicated yourself, it isn't scalable.